# How to speed up / optimize ionic mobile app (android)?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

It takes a long time to start/load the app. And Also when I navigate to pages there is a delay of 2,3 seconds. Overall it is slower than normal android Apps. How do I reduce loading time and speed up the App for Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ionic guys are working hard so the 4.0 version of Ionic gets faster. Just check [this tweet](https://twitter.com/manucorporat/status/977135513797910530) from one of the Ionic's core developers to see the performance improvements in 4.0 alpha versions.

I also recommend you to build your .apk in an optimized way. This is the command I use in order to build the .apk for production, which **makes the app faster and smaller**:

`ionic cordova build android --prod --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs --release`

Answer (score 1):

Try production build.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```